# Script to Move File from One Network to Other (UNC Paths)

Tags: batch-file

Could anyone please help in modifying my script to move the files from one network to another (using UNC paths)?

I have tried like below (sample script), but its showing error like: *"Syntax Incorrect, Path not found etc"*.

Also please let me know what else steps needed, like Mapping, Authentication etc etc.

```
@echo off

net use Z:\\Network1\MyFiles
net use W:\\Network2

move /Y Z:\Notepad\*.txt  W:\Notepad
echo
pause
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NET USE Z: \\Network1\MyFiles
NET USE W: \\Network2\MyFiles2
move Z:\Notepad*.txt W:\Notepad
pause
```

---

```
The syntax of this command is:

NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ROBOCOPY to move files, and it has native support for UNC paths

```
robocopy \\Network1\MyFiles \\Network2 MyFiles /mov /is /it /njh /njs /ndl /ns /nc /np /nc
```

If you really prefer to use MOVE, then you only need to map one UNC path. The MOVE command supports UNC paths for the source, but not the target. I would use PUSHD to map the UNC path, because then you don't have to know a free drive letter - PUSHD will automatically assign the first available letter.

```
pushd \\Network2
move /y \\Network1\MyFiles .
popd
```

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe